# Find first n non zero values in in numpy 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I would like to know the fastest way to extract the indices of the first `n` non zero values per column in a 2D array.

For example, with the following array:

```
arr = [
  [4, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 4, 0, 0],
  [2, 0, 9, 0],
  [6, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 7, 0, 0],
  [3, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 2, 0, 0],
```

With `n=2` I would have `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]` as xs and `[0, 3, 2, 5, 3]` as ys. 2 values in the first and second columns and 1 in the third.

Here is how it is currently done:

```
x = []
y = []
n = 3
for i, c in enumerate(arr.T):
  a = c.nonzero()[0][:n]
  if len(a):
    x.extend([i]*len(a))
    y.extend(a)
```

In practice I have arrays of size `(405, 256)`.

Is there a way to make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method, although quite confusing as it uses a lot of functions, that does not require sorting the array (only a linear scan is necessary to get non null values):

```
n = 2

# Get indices with non null values, columns indices first
nnull = np.stack(np.where(arr.T != 0))

# split indices by unique value of column
cols_ids= np.array_split(range(len(nnull[0])), np.where(np.diff(nnull[0]) > 0)[0] +1 )

# Take n in each (max) and concatenate the whole
np.concatenate([nnull[:, u[:n]] for u in cols_ids], axis = 1)
```

outputs:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 2, 5, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `argsort`, it gives a different order though:

```
n = 2
m = arr!=0

# non-zero values first
idx = np.argsort(~m, axis=0)

# get first 2 and ensure non-zero
m2 = np.take_along_axis(m, idx, axis=0)[:n]
y,x = np.where(m2)

# slice
x, idx[y,x]
# (array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1]), array([0, 2, 3, 3, 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dislocation comparison for the row results of the transposed nonzero:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> i, j = arr.T.nonzero()
>>> mask = np.concatenate([[True] * n, i[n:] != i[:-n]])
>>> i[mask], j[mask]
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 3, 2, 5, 3], dtype=int64))
```